# Вирус и браузер

Tags: вирусы

Имеется огромная проблема, которая меня значительно вымотала и достала. В браузере (Chrome и Opera)через определённые промежутки времени открывается вкладка-реклама. Так же данный вирус создаёт папки в директории ..\AppData\Local... Папки именуются типа (Kometa,Bromium,Яндекс и пр.). Все они содержат одну и туже инфу папку User Data\здесь пака с длинной комбинацией латиницы.
Мной применялись следующие действия:

1. Сканирование и чистка ADWCleaner
2. Сканирование и чисткаMailwareFight
3. Ручное удаление папок, создаваемых автоматически вирусом
4. Скинирование eset nod
5. Сброс настроек брайзеров и чистка куков
6. Пробовал переустановить браузер (Chrom), но копировал старую папку User data в новый браузер.

Какие советы по решению данного вопроса? Заранее спасибо.
Прикрепляю ссылку на архив с одной из папок, которая генерится в AppData.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Столкнулся с подобной проблемой у жены на компе

Короче, прикол в том, что в "**Планировщике задач**" какая-то программа при установке создала таски на запуск браузера и переход на определенный `URL`

Еще видел таску, которая запускает не браузер, а приложение из папки Windows `OpenWith.exe`, которое тебе предлагает самому выбрать браузер, через который открыть)

Называются они в стиле `InternetD`, `InternetB`, `InternetSC`

Стоит выполнение каждые 22 минуты

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Соответственно никакие антивирусы и прочее ПО не находит ничего)

Удаляешь таски и всё ок, кстати в инете я не нашел об этом ничего

Comment: Действительно в планировщике был запущен похожий процесс InternetDB.Удалил и реклама, вроде, пока перестала доставать.Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @DenisDanilov можно ответ галочкой отметить)

Comment: Извиняюсь, на радостях забыл)Просто так измучился с этим вирусным трешем.Ещё раз спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

1. Есть программка malwarebytes anti-malware.
2. Еще поискать в реестре что-нибудь по ключевым словам (например, название сайта). Можно программкой regedit
3. В свойствах браузера посмотреть, не приписано ли что-нибудь лишнее после пути к .exe

Comment: Malwarebyte - отличный выбор для чистки, также в довесок к нему тянем утилиту "jv16", которая просто изумительно вычищает реестр от всякого мусора. Ну и "ABP" в расширения.

Answer (score 0):

Можете попробовать следующие трюки:

1. Найдите папки, которые создает вирус для своей работы. Удалите их, создав на их месте одноименные файлы (если папка была без расширения - то и файл надо создавать без расширения, это важно!).
2. Найдите папки, которые создает вирус для своей работы. Отредактируйте права на эти папки, выставив для группы "All Users"/"Все" полный запрет доступа.